# RestKit - Sync Data Base with local JSON file

Tags: ios, json, core-data, synchronization, restkit-0.20

I have provided with a sample JSON file (for testing purpose I haven't early access to the web service). after loading the file and converting to `NSDictionary` how can I use that dictionary and sync my data base? all the tutorials and samples I've read use web service

I have created my  mapping for all of the objects and applied their relationship.

an example:

```
+ (RKEntityMapping *) mapTableInManagedObjectStore:(RKManagedObjectStore *)managedObjectStore
{
    RKEntityMapping *tableMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Table" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    tableMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"tableID"];
    [tableMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                       @"ID":@"tableID",
                                                       @"TableNumber":@"tableNumber",
                                                       @"NumberOfChairs":@"numberOfChairs"}];

    return tableMapping;
}
```

Comment: Did you try using a file URL? It used to work but I seem to recall that something broke it. Otherwise, just host the file somewhere and then change the URL you use to access it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did and works well:

```
 // read file
NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:contentPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

NSString* MIMEType = @"application/json";
NSError* parseError;

NSData *data = [myJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id parsedData = [RKMIMETypeSerialization objectFromData:data MIMEType:MIMEType error:&parseError];
if (parsedData == nil && parseError) {
    NSLog(@"Cannot parse data: %@", parseError);
}

//convert NSData to NSDictionary
NSError *errorJson=nil;
NSDictionary* responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:lookServerResponseData options:kNilOptions error:&errorJson];
 NSDictionary *tableDic = responseDict;

//perform mapping
    RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [HAObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore;
    Table *table = [[Table findAll] firstObject];
    RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource *mappingDataSource = [[RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext cache:managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache];

    RKMappingOperation  *mappingOperation = [[RKMappingOperation alloc] initWithSourceObject:tableDic destinationObject:table mapping:[MappingProvider mapTablebjectStore:managedObjectStore]];

    mappingOperation.dataSource = mappingDataSource;
    NSError *error = nil;
    [mappingOperation performMapping:&error];
```

RKMappingOperation job is to map values from source object to destination object.
now table attributes are updated with tableDic values. (table is kind of `NSManagedObject`)